# when using android NDK NativeWindow to display image, how to lock orientation?

Tags: android, image, window, native, android-ndk

In android NDK, when use NativeWindow to display image, how to lock the orientation? Basically, when the phone rotate, I want the image relatively still to the phone. (See the illustration below, in case I’m not clear).

```
_____
|  ^ |                
|  o |  
|____|   

_______ 
| <  o |
|______|
```

I followed the sample program native plasma, and used the ANativeWindow_Buffer. My image resolution is 480x800, the native window’s resolution is also 480x800 if I hold the phone in portrait mode. However if I hold the phone in landscape mode, the native window size becomes 800x480, and my displayed image mess up unless I change how I fill the buffer. I wonder if there is a way to set the native window buffer size always to 480x800, and prevent it change when the phone rotates.

I see in the ANativeWindow API, there is a function, ANativeWindow_setBuffersGeometry
I tried to use it to set the buffer geometry to 480 by 800, but it did not have any effect.

Please help. 
Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should still be able to handle this in your Java side manifest, I believe...

in the activity tag, add

```
android:screenOrientation="portrait"
```

Comment: Excellent. Feel free to accept the answer if you found it helpful.